# MongoDB how to group objects in array and find the top 3

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pipeline, pymongo-3.x, arrayobject

I want to find which are the top 3 places (if it has) that a user comments most.

More specifically, I have a collection review which has the `user_id` and the `business_id` and a collection business which has `business_id` and longitude and latitude. If the user has made a review from the location (38.551126, -110.880452) and (38.999999, -110.000000),
we can say the user has 2 reviews at this location (38, -110).

Collection.review:

```
{
  "review_id": "KU_O5udG6zpxOg-VcAEodg",
  "user_id": "mh_-eMZ6K5RLWhZyISBhwA",
  "business_id": "XQfwVwDr-v0ZS3_CbbE5Xw",
  "stars": 3,
  "useful": 0,
  "funny": 0,
  "cool": 0,
  "text": "If you decide to eat here, ...",
  "date": "2018-07-07 22:09:11"
}
```

collection.business:

```
{
  "business_id": "XQfwVwDr-v0ZS3_CbbE5Xw",
  "name": "Turning Point of North Wales",
  "address": "1460 Bethlehem Pike",
  "city": "North Wales",
  "state": "PA",
  "postal_code": "19454",
  "latitude": 40.2101961875,
  "longitude": -75.2236385919,
  "stars": 3,
  "review_count": 169,
  "is_open": 1,
  "attributes": Object
  "categories": "Restaurants, Breakfast & Brunch, Food",
  "hours": Object
}
```

I am a beginner at mongodb, the only pipeline I have some result is this.

```
review.aggregate([{
 $match: {
  user_id: {
   $in: [some_list]
  }
 }
}, {
 $lookup: {
  from: 'business',
  localField: 'business_id',
  foreignField: 'business_id',
  as: 'business'
 }
}, {
 $unwind: {
  path: '$business'
 }
}, {
 $group: {
  _id: '$user_id',
  coordinates: {
   $push: {
    latitude: {
     $toInt: '$business.latitude'
    },
    longitude: {
     $toInt: '$business.longitude'
    }
   }
  },
  places: {
   $sum: 1
  }
 }
}])
```

**output**

```
_id: "xoZvMJPDW6Q9pDAXI0e_Ww"
coordinates: Array
    0: Object
        latitude: 39
        longitude: -119
    1: Object
        latitude: 39
        longitude: -119
    2: Object
        latitude: 39
        longitude: -119
    3: Object
        latitude: 39
        longitude: -119
    4: Object
        latitude: 39
        longitude: -119
places: 5
```

After that i process the result in python. Is there someway to do it from the pipeline immediately
and have the result something like this (and limited to top 3)

```
_id: "xoZvMJPDW6Q9pDAXI0e_Ww"
top_places: Array
    0: Object
        latitude: 39
        longitude: -119
    1: Object
        latitude: 23
        longitude: 56
```

Comment: how much of a "change" can the lat of long field have before it's considered two different locations?

Comment: As you are doing $push, the mentioned output cannot be the o/p.

Comment: @TomSlabbaert As long as the int part of the lat and long is the same is one location e.g (23.999999, 21.999999)=>(23,21) one location, (23,000001, 21.000001)=>(23, 21) same location, (23.999999, 22.000001)=>(23,22) different location

Comment: @Gibbs I guess o/p means output. It can be the output but I have to do more process in python for the data that I need I just wondered if there is a way mongo can do it for me

Comment: So `(23.999999, 22.000000)` => `(23, 22)` wouldn't be anywhere near `(24.000000, 22.000000)` => `(24, 22)` even though they are less than a handspan apart? Are you sure that you wouldn't rather use a different metric, e.g. a calculated great circle distance or at least checking the delta of the lat's and long's against a limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add an additional grouping stage, first group by location and user and only then group by user, like so:

```
db.review.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "business",
      localField: "business_id",
      foreignField: "business_id",
      as: "business"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$business"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        user: "$user_id",
        latitude: {
          $toInt: "$business.latitude"
        },
        longitude: {
          $toInt: "$business.longitude"
        }
      },
      places: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.user",
      coordinates: {
        $push: {
          latitude: "$_id.latitude",
          longitude: "$_id.longitude",
          
        }
      },
      places: {
        $sum: "$places"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZlGU5bM7OrL)

Comment: Its almost correct but it doesn't show which are the 3 top locations, and also for only 100 records the first group takes about 30sec to execute i have 1m records, thank you very much tho.

Comment: You didnt ask for it in your question but here is how you can do it, https://mongoplayground.net/p/sllHgXxZswE. you just need to save the place throughout the group stages..

regarding performances you did not raise this as a concern, I recommend you make sure the right indexes are exists for both collections, apart from that there is not much else to optimize here.